# Show on one report a database field column with more data entries (records)

Tags: crystal-reports

I have never worked with Crystal Reports and I want to do something with CR. If some translations of fields are wrong, then I apologize, because I use the German version.

It is about a report. Have inserted the databases correctly and successfully in Crystal Reports. Many database fields have only one data record. But two independent tables - which have to do with each other only with the primary data source - have two or even more entries / records.

How do I get the fields to be written to the report only once, without duplicates? Because if I put them in the appropriate Details section, then multiple reports are created. As many as there are entries in the corresponding column. What are the solution possibilities?

I want to have everything bundled as separate lists on a single report page. I tried some code snippets I found, of course adapted to my databases, but very often I get an error message. Coming from the C# world, I may have to think a bit simpler here.

I once thought to store all data entries of a column over a loop in a string, but somehow I can't manage to write the code. And to be honest I don't know if I have to put the formula field in details, header, page header or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use ***Insert, Subreport...*** and place each "list" in a separate subreport.

You can position the subreports side by side.

Comment: Does it matter for a subreport if you use the same data source? Is there anything to consider?

Comment: Each subreport can have a completely different data source.